# How to Split more than the Active Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to get a cell to split down the based on the values returned from a formula.
It wont let me upload a photo so I will do the best I can to explain.

The following is my code to split the cell:

```
Sub splitText()
Dim splitVals As Variant, totalVals As Long, I As Integer
splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row,ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
End Sub
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get my program set so that it will split all of the cells in column D, instead of just the active cell.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) might help you

Comment: Look into "For Loops vba" or "Do Loops vba" or "Loop through rows vba".  Google will have a ton of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
    Sub splitText()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim splitVals As Variant, totalVals As Long, I As Integer

    For Each r In Range("D:D").Cells
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            splitVals = Split(r.Value, " ")
            totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
            Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 1), Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
        End If
    Next r


    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! This totally makes sense, but now it is not returning anything... I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but the data in my D cells is four digit numbers separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub splitText()
   Dim splitVals As Variant, totalVals As Long
   Dim N as single
   splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
   totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
   For N = 0 to totalVals
      ActiveCell.offset(0, 1 + N) = splitVals(N)
      ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).select
   Next N
End Sub
```

This sub is only to split text for a single cell, which is your active cell.
If you need to split for multiple cells, then will need to loop this function for each cells.

Comment: ok thanks! That makes sense... but it is still only splitting the active cell. I have tried modifying this code to get it to split the cells down column D beginning at row 5, but can not seem to get it.

Comment: yes, only for activecell, because we are using ActiveCell, add in new code to move the active cell to next row

Comment: but my recommendation is using Cells(), rather using ActiveCell, keep going